# C Programming compare rows and columns of 2d array

Tags: c, arrays, comparison, rows

Hey guys so I am trying to compare the rows and columns of a 2d array to see if there are any pairs of letters directly near each other. I can make the array no problem, but my only problem is I have no idea how to go about comparing the rows separately, and then the columns..If you could help me out at all that would be amazing! thank you!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

int main( void )
{  

int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int countX = 0;
int countY = 0;
srandom( (unsigned) time(NULL) );
char array[x][y]; 


for (x=0;x<20;x++)
    {
     for (y=0; y<30; y++)
      {
       array[x][y] = random() % 26 + 65;
       printf("%c ",array[x][y]);
      }
printf("\n");
    }
printf ("\n\n");

return ( 0 ) ;

}
```

Comment: Sounds like what you're trying to do is a crossword. Should put that in the question. Second, you declare your array with x and y, which are both zero.

Comment: Can you give a simple example for such a matrix and what defines a pair? Is `array[x][y] == array[x+1][y+1]` also counted as a pair?

Comment: char array[0][0]; is not a very large array. Less than 20 or 30 for sure. Also, I'd change 65 to 'A'.

Comment: As Phillip said, you need to define "directly near each other"

Comment: Are you trying to compare strings, (i.e. does stringA equal stringB), or are you just trying to compare the occurrence of `char` as in `array[x][y] == 'f';` and `array[x+3][y+3]=='f';` therefore a pair?

Comment: @ryyker I am trying to compare the occurrence of the char, so as and example if the array printed out to be
V V T A B C...
...

then the function would print out like "rows has 1 pair"

Comment: Please indent properly. It's a matter of respect when you ask for help.

Comment: @SalZ. - see my new answer below to address your questions.  It includes example outputs, and explanations of how/why they were created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the matching pairs in columns, scan over each row except the last, and for each column, compare the value at `array[row][col]` with the value at `array[row+1][col]` and report matches.

To find the matching pairs in rows, scan over each column except the last, and for each row, compare the value at `array[row][col]` with the value at `array[row][col+1]` and report matches.

For example:

```
V U F B L O H W P O E G R K Z Q T D Z S I P C W R W F G G Y 
Z B T G D E U M C J A I P S U Q I N U K F C B K Y S G G Y M 
E Y Q X G V D B H H K I P C A J S K X O W E Q Y O R Q W X R 
J D R Z D X U G A D O L L F N N R H A Q W W U O U L F N H E 
G S K Z R N Y N V Z R J K E R Z S I I S Y E Q U T L F A A P 
H I H R H B G F Q B E J N Q O E R I O A C O G S I B F Q E H 
H L P O E W R K E I N K R A D H E U R U W T I D O R G T J K 
B Q V S G B R Y L V G Z H Z B K J I H A C D U L I I E P D P 
Z G F X Z L Y S L M N T N W T O H C W Q C Z V Y M E I Q V M 
H U S M T T Z S L N G A G T X Z H G D G W I H R G T X P L S 
D U P V G I R H A C U G F B B C C L K I R G Q A Z Y V X P I 
R S C G Q K P H R R L O A Q R B U T M E B F M T H M S C L H 
K C C O J S Y A B S R M G R F Z V B U J G W R S R Y G J D R 
T P W V E H P E H Q W A E E S L D P N Y Y T W R N N S W Z V 
P S K L P Q S E V Z U T A A Y U M B L Z Z L U X D H L V F K 
S V E E G T V B X S A T L C T L Y F N J G O X A M A K Z X P 
J P K P T T I Q U H K W A Y Z V J Z B Y L H N I K B K U A H 
L L W W A R R K I L R U H R S I O C I P C T Z R D L S N H U 
U S H S Q H J H T T S K O A D I K S M S J P N K G Q V Z D C 
V Z X D R N M D V G Y P S O R W X C O J W Z Y K K F C H G I 


Scan columns:
a[ 0][15] = a[ 1][15] = Q
a[ 0][27] = a[ 1][27] = G
a[ 1][11] = a[ 2][11] = I
a[ 1][12] = a[ 2][12] = P
a[ 2][20] = a[ 3][20] = W
a[ 3][ 3] = a[ 4][ 3] = Z
a[ 3][25] = a[ 4][25] = L
a[ 3][26] = a[ 4][26] = F
a[ 4][11] = a[ 5][11] = J
a[ 4][17] = a[ 5][17] = I
a[ 4][26] = a[ 5][26] = F
a[ 5][ 0] = a[ 6][ 0] = H
a[ 6][ 6] = a[ 7][ 6] = R
a[ 7][ 8] = a[ 8][ 8] = L
a[ 7][20] = a[ 8][20] = C
a[ 8][ 7] = a[ 9][ 7] = S
a[ 8][ 8] = a[ 9][ 8] = L
a[ 8][16] = a[ 9][16] = H
a[ 9][ 1] = a[10][ 1] = U
a[10][ 7] = a[11][ 7] = H
a[11][ 2] = a[12][ 2] = C
a[13][ 7] = a[14][ 7] = E
a[14][11] = a[15][11] = T
a[15][ 5] = a[16][ 5] = T
a[15][26] = a[16][26] = K
a[17][15] = a[18][15] = I
a[18][23] = a[19][23] = K
Scan rows:
a[17][ 0] = a[17][ 1] = L
a[12][ 1] = a[12][ 2] = C
a[15][ 2] = a[15][ 3] = E
a[17][ 2] = a[17][ 3] = W
a[ 9][ 4] = a[ 9][ 5] = T
a[16][ 4] = a[16][ 5] = T
a[17][ 5] = a[17][ 6] = R
a[ 2][ 8] = a[ 2][ 9] = H
a[11][ 8] = a[11][ 9] = R
a[18][ 8] = a[18][ 9] = T
a[ 3][11] = a[ 3][12] = L
a[13][12] = a[13][13] = E
a[14][12] = a[14][13] = A
a[10][13] = a[10][14] = B
a[ 3][14] = a[ 3][15] = N
a[10][15] = a[10][16] = C
a[ 4][17] = a[ 4][18] = I
a[13][19] = a[13][20] = Y
a[14][19] = a[14][20] = Z
a[ 3][20] = a[ 3][21] = W
a[19][23] = a[19][24] = K
a[ 7][24] = a[ 7][25] = I
a[13][24] = a[13][25] = N
a[ 1][26] = a[ 1][27] = G
a[ 0][27] = a[ 0][28] = G
a[ 4][27] = a[ 4][28] = A
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

enum { MAXROW = 20, MAXCOL = 30 };

int main(void)
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    char array[MAXROW][MAXCOL];

    srandom(time(NULL));

    for (x = 0; x < MAXROW; x++)
    {
        for (y = 0; y < MAXCOL; y++)
        {
            array[x][y] = random() % 26 + 'A';
            printf("%c ", array[x][y]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    printf("Scan columns:\n");
    for (int row = 0; row < MAXROW - 1; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < MAXCOL; col++)
        {
            if (array[row][col] == array[row+1][col])
                printf("a[%2d][%2d] = a[%2d][%2d] = %c\n", row, col, row+1, col, array[row][col]);
        }
    }

    printf("Scan rows:\n");
    for (int col = 0; col < MAXCOL - 1; col++)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < MAXROW; row++)
        {
            if (array[row][col] == array[row][col+1])
                printf("a[%2d][%2d] = a[%2d][%2d] = %c\n", row, col, row, col+1, array[row][col]);
        }
    }

    return(0);
}
```

If you don't have C99 support, you can declare `row` and `col` at the top of the function instead of in the loops as needed.

Answer (score 1):

***[edit - new information, old code removed]:***

In this code segment, I generate the rows and columns similar to what you have done, but because I do not have the `random();` function, I wrote my own.  And in it, I made it possible to adjust so that it would guarantee pairs within the created sample.  This allows you to see that the "pairs" counts within the columns and rows occur correctly.  Without this ability to test, I found that the random function rarely created contiguous samples of the same value (a pair).  Look for the comments in the `random()` function, and run it both ways, with `clock()` commented (two places), and uncommented.

***Modified `random()` function:***

```
trying = 1;
//val = clock(); //To force pairs, comment here
while(trying)
{
    //while(val == clock()); //To force pairs, comment here 
    srand(clock());
```

***Here is the new code:*** (without modification shown just above)

```
#include <ansi_c.h>
enum {
    row,
    col
};

#define ROWS 20
#define COLS 30

int GetNumPairs(int arr[ROWS][COLS], int index, int type);
int random(int min, int max);


int main(void)
{
    int i=0, j=0;
    int array[ROWS][COLS];
    int countPairs[260];
    //int countPairsRows[260];

    memset(array, 0, sizeof(int)*ROWS*COLS);

    for(i=0;i<ROWS;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<COLS;j++)
        {
            array[i][j] = random('A', 'Z'); //min, max value to be produced
            printf("%c", array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    memset(countPairs, 0, sizeof(int)*260);//clear memory first
    //pairs in columns, must traverse rows from 0 to 19
    for(i=1;i<=ROWS;i++)
    {
        countPairs[i]=GetNumPairs(array, i-1, row);
        printf("row %d has %d pairs\n", i, countPairs[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    memset(countPairs, 0, sizeof(int)*260);//clear memory again
    //pairs in rows, must traverse columns from 0 to 29
    for(i=1;i<=COLS;i++)
    {
        countPairs[i]=GetNumPairs(array, i-1, col);
        printf("col %d has %d pairs\n", i, countPairs[i]);
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}


int random(int min, int max)
{
    int random=0, trying=0;
    clock_t val;


    trying = 1;
    val = clock(); //To force pairs, comment here
    while(trying)
    {
        while(val == clock()); //To force pairs, comment here 
        srand(clock());
        random = (rand()/32767.0)*(max+1);
        ((random >= min)) ? (trying = 0) : (trying = 1);
    }

    return random;
}

int GetNumPairs(int arr[ROWS][COLS], int index, int type)
{
    int i, j,cnt=0;
    switch(type){
        case row:
            for(i=0;i<COLS-1;i++)
            {
                    if(arr[index][i] == arr[index][i+1])
                    {
                        cnt++;  
                    }
            }
            break;
        case col:
            for(j=0;j<ROWS-1;j++)
            {
                    if(arr[j][index] == arr[j+1][index])
                    {
                        cnt++;  
                    }
            }
            break;
    };

    return cnt;
}
```

Following are two images showing (1) normally generated samples, (small number of pairs, to 0 pairs), and the second is data generated with the commented `clock()` function to force many pairs:

***Normally generated samples:***
[image]

***Samples created with modified random() function:***
[image]

Comment: this is way over my head, I was just trying to create an array that printed out 20 rows and 30 columns, and in the same function compare all the letters by traversing the rows first and printing out how many pairs there are, then traversing the columns to see how many pairs there are there..

Comment: See my edit, with explanations of how to get force pairs for test, and how to run without forcing pairs.